# Bijection from $N$ to $R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that there exists a bijection between $N$ and $Q$ but everyone says its common knowledge that It's impossible to find a bijection between $N$ to $R$, so I tried to prove it and I'm thoroughly lost I don't even know how can I find a contradiction.

Umm I'm still a beginner, I'm on terminal high school
So can anyone illuminate to me how can we even prove this, is it easy or is it some kind of famous demonstration?

Comment: It's pretty hard to sort out on your own, but you'll be able to follow the argument.  Start with [Cantor's diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)

Comment: What is a terminal high school?

Comment: It's 12th year in france I guess